# Is there any "object" in monogame for windows phone 8, that is similar to Toast in Android?

Tags: android, monogame, windows-phone-8

The title pretty much sums it all.

Is there any "object" in monogame for windows phone 8 (for monogame to be exact), that is similar to Toast in Android?

My purpose is to give a notification / hint at what user do, until certain period / until next user input.

For example:
If the player tapped "attack", then there is text shown "Select your target" in either top or bottom screen. Just like Toast in android.

Note 1 : I can do it manually, but i'm just curious. If I can use a pre-made function (such as Toast) it'll be simpler to implement, rather than making it myself.

Note 2 : Mine is a turn based tactic game (such as FF Tactic)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think MonoGame has anything built in like that. Your best bet will be to write your own wrapper around the existing Toast functionality for each platform or create your own in game system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone has integrated functionality for displaying toast notifications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx

But I don't think it's what you are looking for, since they always appear in the top part of the screen and are meant for showing notifications when the app isn't active.

Comment: Yeah that's not what i'm looking for. Thanks for your answer anyway.